# Nvidia x server messed up my monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm not really experienced with building pcs or ubuntu, but I built one on ubuntu 18.04 and I got a nvidia 1650 super for it today, I tried installing drivers, I first went to nvidia website and got the 1650 super for linux amd64, and ran the file, but it didn't do anything I could notice. Later, I googled and tried out this website https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/, did the instructions and now my screen looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNS8E.jpg please help it is extremely zoomed in

Comment: Are you certain that you have plugged your monitor into the output of the graphics card? And not by accident on the graphics output of the motherboard of your computer?

Comment: Yes I plugged the hdmi into the graphics card (edit: it was fine just really slow before I installed the drivers)

Comment: What strikes me as a bit odd is that you went online looking for drivers for the graphics card. Usually this is not necessary with Ubuntu as it detects your card automatically and uses the appropriate driver for it.

Comment: Originally, i was using integrated vega 8 which worked just fine, but when I got the graphics card it was really weird (slightly reddish hue, much worse than integrated graphics, even though it should easily beat vega 8). Also, I kind of fixed my monitor, by reinstalling ubuntu but i have encountered new problems, such as clicking settings makes monitor black, then i have to sign in, google chrome also crashes after i open it, the applications list is weird, (no scrolling animation, just brings me instantly to next page)

Comment: It sound like you have bigger issues than just a non-functional graphics driver. If it is a new computer and you don't have much data yet I would suggest to clear the entire drive and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch.